# React Native: DatePickerIOS - how to keep "Date" value after return from other pages

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a scene use DatePickerIOS component. The document example inits a new Date() and uses state to save and update Date value. So if I go to another page and back, the time will change and I need reset this value.

The document usage:

```
static defaultProps = {
    date: new Date()
    timeZoneOffsetInHours: (-1) * (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() / 60,
};

state = {
    date: this.props.date,
    timeZoneOffsetInHours: this.props.timeZoneOffsetInHours,
};

onDateChange(date) {
    this.setState({date: date});
};

render(){
    return(
            <View style={styles.wrap}>
                <View style={styles.datePickerIOS}>
                    <DatePickerIOS
                        date={this.state.date}
                        mode="time"
                        timeZoneOffsetInMinutes={this.state.timeZoneOffsetInHours * 60}
                        onDateChange={this.onDateChange.bind(this)}
                        minuteInterval={10}
                    />
                </View>
```

I try use props and persist this data into local storage.

```
static defaultProps = {
    date: new Date()
    timeZoneOffsetInHours: (-1) * (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() / 60,
};

state = {
    date: this.props.date,
    timeZoneOffsetInHours: this.props.timeZoneOffsetInHours,
};

componentWillMout() {
    this.props.updateDate(this.props.date)
}

onDateChange(date) {
    this.setState({date: date});
    this.props.updateDate(date)
};

render(){
    return(
            <View style={styles.wrap}>
                <View style={styles.datePickerIOS}>
                    <DatePickerIOS
                        date={this.props.alarmConfig.date}
                        mode="time"
                        timeZoneOffsetInMinutes={this.state.timeZoneOffsetInHours * 60}
                        onDateChange={this.onDateChange.bind(this)}
                        minuteInterval={10}
                    />
                </View>
```

updateDate(date) is an action

```
export function updateDate(date){
return {
    type: "UPDATE_DATE",
    date: date,
    }
}

export function alarmConfig(state=initialState, action){
switch(action.type) {
    case types.UPDATE_DATE:
        return {
            ...state,
            date: action.date
        };
```

if I do like that, the value under alarmConfig.date is a string, so I get a error, because the DatePickerIOS Date prop requires a Date type.

if I just change like Below:

```
<DatePickerIOS
      date={this.state.date}
      mode="time"
      timeZoneOffsetInMinutes={this.state.timeZoneOffsetInHours * 60}
      onDateChange={this.onDateChange.bind(this)}
      minuteInterval={10}
 />
```

The value under alarmConfig.date is a Date, same with state.date

What reason does cause this situation? And how to change the code to reach my aim?

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

- If you're storing the date in your redux store (like I assume your doing from the code above), you should indeed be mapping the application state to your compononent's props with `mapStateToProps`.

See: http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html#implementing-container-components

- There's no reason why you couldn't store a `Date` object in your Redux store so your error `alarmConfig.date is a string` is maybe caused by the initial state. What does your `initialState` variable look like?
- If you still need to serialize the Date as a String, take a look at [momentjs.com](http://momentjs.com).